# How do you 'turn off' the "More" link in Flexipage list views?

Tags: salesforce1-app, flexipages

I would like it if the More option did not appear when all the records are already being displayed as it is and the link does not in fact bring up more, specifically with list other than recent items.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible. I would create an idea for this in the ideas.salesforce.com .